# Transferring subclasses with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, class, inheritance

I have a little problem with transferring subclasses with WCF.
I want to create a general 'feedback' class, and subclassed from feedback: Succes-class and Failure-class (failure has an errorcode and description). This should enable the client to do something like this:

```
If (myWCFclient.authenticate(user, password) is Succes)
{
..
}
```

In my WCF datacontracts, I defined it this way:

```
[DataContract]
public class Feedback : IFeedback
{ 
}

[DataContract]
public class Succes : Feedback
{
}

[DataContract]
public class Failure : Feedback
{
    [DataMember]
    public int errorCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String description { get; set; }
}
```

This works very well, my operation contracts look like this:

```
[OperationContract]
Feedback Authenticate(String email, String password);
```

But in my 'client' application, where I receive those classes, I only find 'Feedback' as a class, 'Succes' and 'Failure' are nowhere to be found.

[image]

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Should I define those 'Succes' and 'Failure' classes different in my DataContracts because they are subclassing 'Feedback'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to resolve this. I think that the following way is the best for you:

```
[DataContract]    
[KnownType(typeof(Success))]
[KnownType(typeof(Failure))]
public class Feedback : IFeedback
{ 
}
```

see also [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: Very nice, this does indeed work, thanks for the MSDN reference, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy generator flattens out the class structure on the client side.  Some ways around this:

**Shared Library**

Create a shared library between the client and server so you don't have to generate proxies.  This may not be a "pure" approach to services, but at least you don't have to generate the proxies each time.

**Partial Classes**

The client side proxies are created as partial classes.  You can create interfaces and implement them in an additional partial class file.

Example:

```
public partial class MyProxy : IFeedback
{
   //you won't have to add code here if the members of IFeedback line up with your data member names.    
}
```